# Updating data to XML file c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with a updating data in XML file in c#. 
Process of updating is ok but the rows are added in bad place.

situation looks like this:

function to update a data:

```
  public void WriteXML(){
        var xmlDoc = XElement.Load("reminds.xml");

        string nowaData = dataData.Text.ToString();
        string nowyOpis = tblOpis.Text.ToString();

        var nowePrzypo = new XElement("przypom",
            new XElement("data", nowaData),
            new XElement("opis", nowyOpis));

        xmlDoc.Element("przypom").Add(nowePrzypo);

        xmlDoc.Save("reminds.xml");
  }
```

XML file before update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dPrzypo>
    <przypom>
        <opis>xxxx</opis>
        <data>xxx</data>
    </przypom>
</dPrzypo>
```

After the update:

```
<dPrzypo>
    <przypom>
        <opis>xxxx</opis>
        <data>xxx</data>
        <przypom>
            <data>10 February 2014</data>
            <opis>hjkjk</opis>
        </przypom>
    </przypom>
</dPrzypo>
```

I want do add data in < dPrzypo> < /dPrzypo>
but this function adding in < przypom> < /przypom>

How it change it?

Comment: Format XML the same way you format code... see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
public void WriteXML(){
    var xmlDoc = XElement.Load("reminds.xml");

    string nowaData = dataData.Text.ToString();
    string nowyOpis = tblOpis.Text.ToString();

    var nowePrzypo = new XElement("przypom",
        new XElement("data", nowaData),
        new XElement("opis", nowyOpis));

    ***xmlDoc.Root.Add(nowePrzypo);***

    xmlDoc.Save("reminds.xml");
```

}

Comment: Doesn't work :(
xmlDoc does have not property Root. 
i have this error:
System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'Root' and no extension method 'Root' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
in line: xmlDoc.Root.Add(nowePrzypo);

Comment: Sorry, the 'Root' property is available on the XDocument object so instead of doing XElement.Load("reminds.xml") you can do XDocument.Load("reminds.xml") so that the 'Root' property is accessible....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on following example

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Load("dPrzypo.xml");
        root.Add(
            new XElement(
                "przypom",
                new XElement("data", "10 February 2014"),
                new XElement("opis", "hjkjk")));
        root.Save("dPrzypo.xml");
    }
```